# Async + Resolve Within If Statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm wondering if there's a way to clean this up or if I need to put a separate resolve() within each if/else like it is now. When I put it outside the three it says message is not defined.

```
function checkAddUser(input) {

    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{

        if(input.email === '') {

            const message = 'Please enter an email address.';

            resolve(message);

        } else if (input.first_name === '') {

            const message = 'Please enter your first name.';

            resolve(message);

        } else {

            const message = false;

            resolve(message);

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: there is no need to even return a promise. the code you wrote is entirely synchronous. you can just return the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to return a promise, since no asynchronous calls are made. To clean up the code I'd suggest this:

```js
function checkAddUser(input) {
        if(input.email === '') {
        
            return 'Please enter an email address.';
            
        }
        
        if (input.first_name === '') {
        
            return 'Please enter your first name.';
            
        }
        
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Only day three in Node world and I come from PHP so asynchronous still confuses me here and there.

Comment: No problem. Yeah it takes a while to wrap your head around. But to also answer your original question: In case there were asynchronous calls you would call resolve 3 times. you could also make 'message' available in the whole function scope and only set/update it in the if statement and then call resolve once at the end of the function. But that is just preference and does not actually make a difference.